# .NET core set auth header for HttpClient service instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Some external service don't provide long lived API keys and in order to make requests to their API i need first make sign-in request which returns authToken and refreshToken.

In my .NET core app I want to have a service class which will return data from this external API.

Right now I registered this service as Typed HttpClient:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IExternalService, ExternalService>();
```

However this way all service methods will have to invoke sign-in method to obtain authHeader before making any other request to this external API.

I want to avoid it and save somewhere the authHeader and use it by all service methods until they receive 403 unauthorized response and only then invoke the sign-in method to get new authToken

What would be the best way to achieve this use case?

Comment: Did you consider using singleton service which manages state of authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the authHeader after the client was created

Add the http client as you doing right now:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IExternalService, ExternalService>();
```

And you have your service class with a method to authenticate and inject the header into the client:

```
public class myService 
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client

    public myService(HttpClient client)
    {
      _client = client;
    }

    private Task Authenticate() 
    { 
        ... your authentication logic here
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Auth", yourToken);
    }

    public MyMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            _client.get....
        }
        catch() 
        {
          catch the unauthorized exception here and call Authenticate()
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in all api calls, put an catch block to catch 401, 403 errors and call the authenticate method again before you re-do the api call.

*For the last part i think you can look at the Polly package to automatizate this process.

As well you can just check the response status code instead of catching an exception:

```
public class myService 
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client

    public myService(HttpClient client)
    {
      _client = client;
    }

    private Task Authenticate() 
    { 
        ... your authentication logic here
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Auth", yourToken);
    }

    public MyMethod()
    {
        try
        {
           var retry = false;
           do
           {
               var response = _client.get....
               if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
               {
                    if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.401 || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.403)
                    {
                         Authenticate();
                         retry = true;
                    }                    
               }
            }
            catch() 
            {
            }
        }
        while (retry);
    }
}
```

Comment: One idea is to check for authentication on the front of the method, that way an infinite loop of calling authentication (if it fails) and then the method is not initiated.